# Can I use the saxon Import-query in C#?

Tags: c#, saxon

I would like to import a predefined XSLT function library into my C# code using the [Import-query](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/extensions/instructions/import-query.html) method described in Saxon but can not find the function in Saxon.API. Is this available and would any one have a code example?

Edit: ok I have found SaxonImportQuery in the api now have to figure out how to instantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saxon:import-query should work in .NET. Like all Saxon extensions, it requires Saxon-PE or higher.

You might also like to consider the `fn:load-xquery-module()` function from XPath 3.1, since this gives access to XQuery-defined functions without any Saxon extensions. It still needs Saxon-PE or higher.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-load-xquery-module